# Typing two line brackets, with single line on right hand side

Tags: equations, brackets

I am trying to type the equation in the photo below, but am having a hard time coming up with a solution. In addition to this, is there a neat way to make the F slightly larger than normal text?

[image: Multi-line equation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
2\sqrt{y}\text{\LARGE $F$}
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2(\beta-1)} 
  & \raisebox{-1.3\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$y^{\beta-1}$}\\[0.75\normalbaselineskip]
1 + \dfrac{1}{2(\beta-1)} & \\
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The right-hand part is not at the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

Nested arrays:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\bigF}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{F}}}

\begin{document}

\[
2\sqrt{y}\,\bigF
  \mleft(
  \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2(\beta-1)} \\[2ex]
  1 + \dfrac{1}{2(\beta-1)}
  \end{matrix}
  & y^{\beta-1}
  \end{array}
  \mright)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]